# Coap.Net Custom Settings

Tags: c#, coap

I'm a bit of a beginner in C# but what I'm coding a CoAP client that will test the throughput and response time of several CoAP servers at once. FYI the application is implemented as a command line program.
The library I'm using is CoAP.NET.

Everything went just fine until I wanted to change the default block size from 512 bytes to something less like 32 bytes.

This is where my understanding of C# fails me, the settings are located in the interface ICoapConfig and the class CoapConfig. These settings just magically loads at some point.

I have tried to do this:

```
CoapConfig conf = new CoapConfig();
conf.DefaultBlockSize = 32;
CoapClient client = new CoapClient(conf);
...
Request req = new Request(Method.PUT);
req.SetPayload(payload, MediaType.TextPlain);
client.Send(req);
```

However the blocksize is still 512 as messages only get transferred blockwise when over 512b.

```
DEBUG - BlockwiseLayer uses MaxMessageSize: 1024 and DefaultBlockSize:512
```

This is the first line of output I get when running the program.

Happy for any help :)

SOLUTION:

```
CoapConfig conf = new CoapConfig();
conf.DefaultBlockSize = 32;
...
Request req = new Request(Method.PUT);
req.SetPayload(payload, MediaType.TextPlain);
req.URI = client.Uri;

IEndPoint _clientEndpoint;
_clientEndpoint = new CoAPEndPoint(conf);
_clientEndpoint.Start();
req.Send(_clientEndpoint);
...
```

I don't really know what this EndPoint thing might be but this lets you use a desired configuration when sending.
FYI: I tried to set the config for the server to but with no success.

Comment: Well posed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can review all of the source code for [CoAP.NET](https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET) on github.

I'm not familiar with this library, but from just a quick review, it looks like the `DefaultBlockSize` configuration property is only referenced by `CoapServer` (not `CoapClient`).

Further evidence is in the [BlockTransferTest](https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET/blob/master/CoAP.Test/BlockwiseTransferTest.cs) fixture, which configures the `CoapServer` with a particular block size on [line 43](https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET/blob/master/CoAP.Test/BlockwiseTransferTest.cs#L43).

You might also check [line 161](https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET/blob/master/CoAP.Test/BlockwiseTransferTest.cs#L161) of that same test class.  It seems like you may be able to provide configuration settings for the endpoint as well.

Comment: Well I solved it! Thanks for the tip on the CoAP.Test Library :D